# React Navigation bar change background on active link

Tags: css, reactjs

Hey I'm just starting to learn React and have a good knowledge of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I can't get this NavBar to change color if it is the active Link I have tried using several different ways but nothing is working for me. I have the layout how I want it I just don't know if I am writing the JSX code wrong but any help or tips would be amazing thanks.

React JSX code for NavBar

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./NavBar.scss";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <ul class="tab-bar">
      <Link to="/" className="tab">
        <li>Flash Cards</li>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/sets" className="tab">
        <li>Sets</li>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/new" className="tab">
        <li>New</li>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/about" className="tab">
        <li>About</li>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/login" className="tab">
        <li>Login</li>
      </Link>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

SCSS for the NavBar

```
$primary-color: #0f9b8e;
$secondary-color: #343837;
$tertiary-color: #03719c;

body {
  background: $secondary-color;
}
.tab-bar {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tab {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: $primary-color;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tab:hover,
.tab:active {
  background: $tertiary-color;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from using state, the other options are:

**1) Simply use [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink)** and `activeClassName`. It will automatically read url and adjust the style based on your url pathname

```js
<NavLink activeClassName="active" className={"tab"} to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
```

**2) Use `useHistory` hook** and read the current url and dynamically adjust the styles

```js
...
const currentRoute = useHistory().location.pathname.toLowerCase();
...
<Link className={currentRoute.includes("home") ? "tab active" : "tab"} to="/home"> 
 Home
</Link>
...
```

Working copy of [code sample (in the codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/active-tab-issue-fix-3t7ss?file=/src/Nav.js)

**Full Code Snippet**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.scss";
const Nav = props => {
  const currentRoute = useHistory().location.pathname.toLowerCase();
  return (
    <div className="tab-bar">
      <Link
        className={currentRoute.includes("home") ? "tab active" : "tab"}
        active
        to="/home"
      >
        Home
      </Link>
      <Link
        className={currentRoute.includes("about") ? "tab active" : "tab"}
        to="/about"
      >
        About
      </Link>
      <NavLink activeClassName="active" className={"tab"} to="/contact">
        Contact
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    import React, {useState} from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    import "./NavBar.scss";

    const NavBar = () => {

  const [currentLink, setCurrentLink] = useState('');

  let background = {};
  switch(currentLink){
  case 'flash':
   background= { backgroundColor: 'red'};
   break;
  case 'sets':
   background= { backgroundColor: 'blue'};
   break;
  case 'new':
   background= { backgroundColor: 'green'};
   break;
  case 'about':
   background= { backgroundColor: 'yellow' };
   break;
  case 'login':
   background= { backgroundColor: 'cyan'};
   break;
  default:
   background = {}
}

  return (
    <ul class="tab-bar" style={background}>
      <Link to="/" className="tab" onClick={() => setCurrentLink('flash')}>
        <li>Flash Cards</li>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/sets" className="tab" onClick={() => setCurrentLink('sets')}>
        <li>Sets</li>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/new" className="tab" onClick={() => setCurrentLink('new')}>
        <li>New</li>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/about" className="tab" onClick={() => setCurrentLink('about')}>
        <li>About</li>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/login" className="tab" onClick={() => setCurrentLink('login')}>
        <li>Login</li>
      </Link>
    </ul>
  );
};

    export default NavBar;
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the following class in your css:

```css
.activeLink{
 background: $tertiary-color;
}
```

Now, create a variable with the class you want to apply when the link is active, like:

```
let ActiveLink = 'activeLink'
```

And then add this to your NavLink :

```
<NavLink to='/home'
className = {({isActive}) => isActive? ActiveLink: 'tab' >

Home
</NavLink>
```

Then it should work.